# Downloading table from Databricks database using REST API

Tags: database, rest, fetch, databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

The thing I was trying to achieve is downloading some data table from Databricks database. The path to the table is gold_test.stockholm_ferries.stockholm_ferries where "gold" is catalog, first "stockholm_ferries" is schema, and second "stockholm_ferries" is the table.
The purpose of downloading the table is using it in another application and possibly modifying the table even further.

I was trying to download the table using DBFS API and Unity Catalog API, but none of them really result in what I need.
With Unity Catalog API I managed to get to the response which contains information about the table (where it is located, what kind of columns does it contain, etc.), but I didn't manage to get the actual table.

I didn't have any success with DBFS API either as it doesn't recognise the DBFS path to the table. Also I'm not sure is it suitable for my purpose because the table will grow and at some point it will be larger than 1 Mb. As I understood DBFS API doesn't allow fetching more than 1 Mb of data.

Is there any best practices for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

If you want access data stored in the table, then Databricks doesn't have the API for it yet (only language specific connectors and ODBC/JDBC), but it will come in the near future, so you will be able to perform SQL queries against tables using REST API.